# autohotkey script only works if it creates a new notepad file each time

Tags: script, autohotkey

I have very little experience with AHK, but after some trial and error I managed to write a script that saved me tons of time. Somehow, it stopped working, and now that I am trying to troubleshoot it, I am stumped by AHK's behavior, as it is working only if I ask the script to create a new Notepad file each time instead of reusing it.

So... my original script allowed me to add lines to an existing tab-separated glossary of terms in Notepad (file name: "lexicon"). I would highlight a term in Chrome and press #s (for "source"), and my term would be copied in my glossary, followed by a tab; then I would highlight the translated term and press #t (for "target"), and it would be copied to the right of the tab, move the cursor to the next line, and minimize notepad. This is my original script:

[image: original ahk script]

I happily used it for months, until one day it stopped working. I have tried to figure out what is wrong with it, and I have been able to pinpoint that the trouble lies with the Notepad file. If instead of

```
 Winactivate, lexicon - Notepad
```

I use

```
 run Notepad
 WinActivate Notepad
```

it will create a new Notepad file each time I press #s, and paste the highlighted term to it, which is *sort of* what I want it to do, except that I need it to happen in my existing "lexicon" file, instead of copying each term in a new, separate instance of Notepad.

Can anyone help me figure out these gremlins?

Thank you very much!!!

Iza

Comment: Have you tried using `Winactivate, lexicon.txt - Notepad` (assuming it has a `.txt` extension)? Because that works for me on v1.1.28.00.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
WinWaitActive, lexicon - Notepad
```

after

```
Winactivate, lexicon - Notepad
```

Try also replacing

```
winactivate, chrome
```

with

```
winactivate, ahk_exe chrome.exe
```

The simplest way to write text to a file is to use [FileAppend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm):

```
#s::
clipboard = ; empty anything in the clipboard
Send ^c ; copies highlighted term
ClipWait, 0.5
FileAppend, %clipboard%%A_Tab%, C:\lexicon.txt
Return


#t::
clipboard = ; empty anything in the clipboard
Send ^c ; copies highlighted term
ClipWait, 0.5   
FileAppend, %clipboard%`n, C:\lexicon.txt
; Run C:\lexicon.txt
Return
```